# Why does 'notion' mean 'sewing-related thing'

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

As eg from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notions_(sewing)

> The term is chiefly in American English... was also formerly used in the phrase "Yankee notions", meaning American products

I'm wondering if anyone can provide a more detailed explanation of how this word came to have its sewing-related meaning.

Comment: I suppose 'fancies' has travelled along a similar route.

Comment: Related: [Word for the superclass of buttons, zippers, and pegs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103525).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good ol' *Oxford English Dictionary* provides:

---

#### **11.** In *plural*.

##### **a.** Chiefly *North American*. Small wares, *esp*. cheap, useful articles. Now chiefly: *spec*. haberdashery; buttons, hooks, ribbon, thread, etc. Yankee notions: see Yankee n. and adj. Compounds b.

1796   *Aurora* (Philadelphia) 1 Feb.   A nest of Boston boxes, commonly called notions.

1803   F. Asbury Jrnl. 13 June (1821) III. 106   How would it tell to the South, that priests were among the notions of Yankee traffick?

1830   J. Galt *Lawrie Todd* I. iii. xiv. 278   Mr. Hoskins and his wife, with a great cargo of wares and other notions in their waggons, arrived.

1842   C. M. Kirkland *Forest Life* II. xxxix. 166   Can I suit ye to-day, ma'am? I've all sorts o' notions.

1876   C. D. Warner *Winter on Nile* xii. 157   The artisans work up ostrich feathers into a variety of ‘notions’.

1902   G. H. Lorimer Lett. *Self-made Merchant to Son* 135   I was traveling out of Chicago for hammer & Hawkins, wholesale dry-goods, gent's furnishings and notions.

1964   McCall's *Sewing in Colour* ii. 22   While making a list of the fabrics and trims needed, check the ‘Notions’ section to see what notions are needed.

1978   A. S. Byatt *Virgin in Garden* xix. 192   Down past the ground floor, a mart of little things, a Vanity Fair of notions and necessities, novelties, and eye-catchers.

1992   E. Lipman *Way Men Act* (1993) 6   They put everything back in the green bag from Goldenberg's department Store—the pattern pieces pinned to the fabric, the notions, [etc.].

##### †**b**. *North American*. Articles or wares of various kinds, forming a miscellaneous cargo on a ship. *Obsolete*.

1805   *Ann. Rev.* 3 31   The Americans.., finding no longer a market there for their lumber cargoes, or notions, as they call them.

1834   F. Marryat *Peter Simple* III. v. 68   Her cargo consisted of what the Americans called notions, that is, in English, an assorted cargo.

1840   R. H. Dana *Two Years before Mast* xxxv. 133   A cargo of fresh provisions, mules, tin bake-pans and other notions.

1872   *Atlantic Monthly* Apr. 398   A schooner full of ‘fish & notions’, a flag of truce to the enemy, and a free range of the seas.

---

So, it seems to me that the older sense is wares of any kind, especially those worth importing (often from the US North) but of sundry nature.

From there, it's changed more into miscellany associated with sewing, clothing, and bric-a-brac.

Why the change, I don't know beyond what those two series of *OED* quotes suggest. Maybe it followed the same path as words like "meat," "deer," and "man" to go from denoting a general category to naming a specific instance of something in that category.

Comment: It seems Maryat's Mr Simple didn't think much of this Yankee linguistic n̶o̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ innovation

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search suggests that the term originated form the southern United States.

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/notion#English), the word **notion** can be used colloquially to mean:

> invention, ingenious device, knicknack

From [New Hampshire Glossary](https://www.cowhampshireblog.com/2006/08/18/new-hampshire-glossary-yankee-notions/):

> goods made in New England, made widely known by traveling Yankee peddlers (salespeople)

It refers to small household goods and tools not produced in the South:

> pins, needles, hooks, scissors, combs, small hardware, buttons, thread, ribbon, minor trinkets, knick-knacks, household industries, nails, clocks, tin ware, and miscellaneous novelties

The association with sewing is perhaps that sewing goods are desirable products, not made at home, which are easy for a travelling salesperson to carry around in large numbers.

Comment: The19th century folk song [Oh Shenandoah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Shenandoah) has the following couplet about a trader going down the Missouri river: "The white man loved the Indian maiden, / With **notions** his canoe was laden." -- i.e. small tradable goods.

Comment: @GeorgeK., I can't help but read a double entendre in that couplet